# C Arena (pool allocator)

Tags: c, memory-management

I wrote a pool allocator (Arena) for a compiler I'm writing.
My use case for this allocator is for storing the parse tree because it allows me to free all the memory at once, so I don't need to keep a reference to each node (which makes the code and logic a big mess).

The implementation uses a singly linked list of blocks. For each block more memory than needed is allocated, and then the "tail" memory is used for allocating.
To align the allocated memory I used `union align` (a union with types that have the strictest alignment requirements according to the book), a trick I learned from the book [C Interfaces and Implementations](https://drh.github.io/cii/).
The `union header` is for calculating the aligned size of the `Arena` struct.

The error if `malloc()` fails was reported using my compiler's error reporting code, so I replaced it with an `fprintf(stderr, ...)` call to report the error, and an `exit(1)` call to stop the execution of the program.

I'm aware that using an existing library would most likely be better, but as I'm writing the compiler for learning purposes, I want to implement all the data structures I use as an exercise.

**Interface:**

```c
#ifndef ARENA_H
#define ARENA_H

#include <stddef.h> // size_t

// The default block size is 10K
#define ARENA_DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE 10 * 1024

typedef struct block Block;

typedef struct arena {
    Block *blocks;
} Arena;

void arenaInit(Arena *a);

void arenaFree(Arena *a);

void *arenaAlloc(Arena *a, size_t size);

void *arenaCalloc(Arena *a, size_t nmemb, size_t size);

#endif // ARENA_H
```

**Implementation:**

```c
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc(), free()
#include <string.h> // memset()
#include "Arena.h"

typedef struct block {
    struct block *prev;
    size_t size, used;
    char data[];
} Block;

union align {
    int i;
    long l;
    long *lp;
    void *p;
    void (*fp)(void);
    float f;
    double d;
    long double ld;
};

union header {
    Arena arena;
    union align a;
};

static inline Block *new_block(size_t size, Block *prev) {
    Block *b = malloc(sizeof(union header) + size);
    // In my compiler, the following check uses the internal error
    // reporting system. I replaced it with fprintf() and exit() calls.
    if(b == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Arena: new_block(): failed to allocate %zu bytes.\n", size);
        exit(1);
    }
    b->size = size;
    b->used = 0;
    b->prev = prev;
    return b;
}

static inline void free_blocks(Block *b) {
    while(b) {
        Block *prev = b->prev;
        free(b);
        b = prev;
    }
}


void arenaInit(Arena *a) {
    a->blocks = new_block(ARENA_DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE, NULL);
}

void arenaFree(Arena *a) {
    free_blocks(a->blocks);
    a->blocks = NULL;
}

void *arenaAlloc(Arena *a, size_t size) {
    size = (size + sizeof(union align) - 1) / sizeof(union align) * sizeof(union align);
    if(a->blocks->used + size > a->blocks->size) {
        // All blocks have at least 10K of memory space.
        a->blocks = new_block(size + ARENA_DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE, a->blocks);
    }
    a->blocks->used += size;
    return (void *)(a->blocks->data + a->blocks->used - size);
}

void *arenaCalloc(Arena *a, size_t nmemb, size_t size) {
    void *p = arenaAlloc(a, nmemb * size);
    memset(p, 0, nmemb * size);
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
#include <stddef.h> // size_t
```

This is my personal pet peeve, but comments after preprocessor instructions are
non standard. All preprocessor in existence can handle it; but since I once needed
to write one, I cringe little inside when I see this.

---

```c
// The default block size is 10K
#define ARENA_DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE 10 * 1024
```

Is there a good reason why the default block size must be in the header?

---

```c
typedef struct arena {
    Block *blocks;
} Arena;

void arenaInit(Arena *a);
```

Have you considered changing the API to hide the implementation to `Arena`?
As in `Arena* arenaInit()`. This has the benefit that you could change the
implementation while remaining ABI compatible. The obvious downside is that
you would not he able to put it on the stack; but IMHO this should not be that
big of a deal.

---

```c
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc(), free()
#include <string.h> // memset()
#include "Arena.h"
```

Unless you are forced to do so (e.g. precompiled headers), you should include
the matching header first. This makes the compiler check for you to be sure the
header compiles on it's own.

---

```c
typedef struct block {
    struct block *prev;
    size_t size, used;
    char data[];
} Block;
```

`size` and `used` should be put on their own line and have their own type.

Technically not wrong, but I find defining an array to have a pointer feels
wrong. I would prefer using `char* data`.

---

```c
union header {
    Arena arena;
    union align a;
};

static inline Block *new_block(size_t size, Block *prev) {
    Block *b = malloc(sizeof(union header) + size);
    // ... 
    b->size = size;
    b->used = 0;
    b->prev = prev;
    return b;
}
```

I understand that you allocate the header with alignment hack, plus the size
of the requested data; what I don't understand is why use the `Arena` and
not `Block`. I think this makes size off by `2*size_t`.

Here I think it would be beneficial if the block size is a power of two. Most
OS allocators will provide a power of two block anyway. (Or multiple of
power of two for large blocks.) This means there
is a chance that it would create less waste.

This is a mater of taste, but using arguments as variables may not be the best
idea. (Applies to all other instances.)

---

```c
void *arenaAlloc(Arena *a, size_t size) {
    size = (size + sizeof(union align) - 1) / sizeof(union align) * sizeof(union align);
```

I think you can improve readability by providing an function that does
the alignment. You probably should also get the sizeof one and use that. Not
for performance reasons but readability.

Consider the following:

```c
static inline size_t align_size(size_t size) {
  static const size_t a = sizeof(union align);
  return (size + a - 1) / a * a;
}

void *arenaAlloc(Arena *a, size_t size) {
    size = align_size(size);
    // ...
}
```

---

```c
    if(a->blocks->used + size > a->blocks->size) {
        // All blocks have at least 10K of memory space.
        a->blocks = new_block(size + ARENA_DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE, a->blocks);
    }
```

I think the `size + ARENA_DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE` is wrong here. You are adding 10k
to a random size resulting in lots of differently sized blocks. I would rather
use `max(size, ARENA_DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE)` or just pass `size` to `new_block` and
then let that round up the size to `ARENA_MIN_BLOCK_SIZE` (of 10k).

---

```c
    a->blocks->used += size;
    return (void *)(a->blocks->data + a->blocks->used - size);
}
```

This is minor, but I would rather take the resulting pointer and return that
instead of first adding size and then subtracting it again.

Here mere mortals like me can immediately understand what is happening:

```c
  void* result = (void *)(a->blocks->data + a->blocks->used); 
  a->blocks->used += size;
  return result;
```

Comment: For the most part I agree with you on comments on preprocessor statements, with one exception, I like to clearly indicate what an #endif ends, since it can be off the screen from the #ifdef/#ifndef statement. There may also be intermediate #endif statements for portable code.

Comment: I personally also like to list what I actually use from an `#include`, so that I know when it’s safe to remove one.

Comment: I don’t think that comments in preprocessing directives are non-standard in C17? The Standard says, “The only white-space characters that shall appear between preprocessing tokens within a preprocessing directive (from just after the introducing `#` preprocessing token through just before the terminating new-line character) are space and horizontal-tab **(including spaces that have replaced comments or possibly other white-space characters in translation phase 3)**.” Preprocessing directives are also stated to be evaluated following translation phase 4.

Comment: Using `char *` in the block struct results in a segmentation fault (even if I initialize it in `new_block()` with `b->data = (char *)(b + offsetof(Block, data);`. I guess using `char[]` as the last field in a struct means that it gets automatically initialized maybe?

Comment: Also, using `Arena` instead of `Block` in `union align` is indeed a bug.
The size of `Arena` is 8 bytes (on x64), the size of `Block` is 24 bytes and the size of `union align` is 16 bytes.
So that means I allocated 8 bytes less (24 - 16 = 8, 16 = `sizeof(union header)` = `sizeof(union align)`) than needed for each block which was what caused some `valgrind` errors about writing after the allocated block I couldn't find the source of.

Comment: I wrote an ANSI C preprocessor, I did not check updated specs. It appears that they fixed it. So my apologies; it was more of a throw away statement and not a strong recomendation.

Comment: The char*/char[] crash is odd. I need to look into it. I generally encounter this in the context of function arguments and there is certainly makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

## General Observations

I agree with @rioki, `#include` statements don't need comments.

If you are using `fprint()` with `stderr` you need to include `stdio.h`, the code does not compile without it, at least when one is using a compiler that follows the C standard.

## Global Entry Points in Header Files

While the `extern` keyword is [optional in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856636/effects-of-the-extern-keyword-on-c-functions), I find that it helps provide self documenting code when one uses it.

```
#ifndef ARENA_H
#define ARENA_H

#include <stddef.h> // size_t

// The default block size is 10K
#define ARENA_DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE 10 * 1024

typedef struct block Block;

typedef struct arena {
    Block* blocks;
} Arena;

extern void arenaInit(Arena* a);
extern void arenaFree(Arena* a);
extern void* arenaAlloc(Arena* a, size_t size);
extern void* arenaCalloc(Arena* a, size_t nmemb, size_t size);

#endif // ARENA_H
```

## Use of the `inline` Keyword in C

In both the C programming language and the C++ programming language the `inline` keyword is a recommendation to the compiler  and the compiler can ignore it. When using the optimizing options the compiler automatically inlines code based on multiple factors.

The use of the `inline` keyword is for performance optimization indicating that function calls can be replace by the code within the function. When you are calling `malloc()` there is no benefit from trying to inline the code since you already have function calls in the code, and the `malloc()` function has a possible system call as well.

## Use System Defined Symbolic Constants

In the new_block() function there is a call to `exit()`, since the code is already including `stdlib.h` rather than using `exit(1)` use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`. The exit status system defined constants [EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status) have been part of the C programming standard for a very long time and also work in C++. They are very helpful in providing self documenting code.

## Declare the Variables as Needed

In the original version of C back in the 1970s and 1980s variables had to be declared at the top of the function. That is no longer the case, and a recommended programming practice to declare the variable as needed. In C the language doesn't provide a default initialization of the variable so variables should be initialized as part of the declaration. For readability and maintainability each variable should be declared and initialized on its own line.

Comment: In `Declare Variables as Needed`, Do you mean to make `arenaInit()` return an `Arena *` so the user must initialize an Arena when declaring it?
Otherwise I don't see any place where I declared a variable before using it.

Comment: @ItaiNelken Here is the important part: ` In C the language doesn't provide a default initialization of the variable so variables should be initialized as part of the declaration. For readability and maintainability each variable should be declared and initialized on its own line.`

Comment: I understood that. What I don't understand is what part of the implementation or interface you are referring to.

Comment: @ItaiNelken the Block struct. You need to declare each member separately.